# CRM Online RetrieveMultiple with OptionSetValueCollection condition

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, crm, query-expressions

I'm trying to retrieve records that contain some optionsetvalue from multi option set pick list.

This line make my code fail:

```
int[] values = GetValues();
query.Criteria.AddCondition(new ConditionExpression(fieldName, 
ConditionOperator.ContainValues, values);
```

When I put the values with a comma separator the code works:

```
query.Criteria.AddCondition(new ConditionExpression(fieldName, 
ConditionOperator.ContainValues, 1,2,3);
```

Only problem is that the values are dyanamic so I can't do that.
The only way I found so far to overcome it was this:

```
FilterExpression filter = new FilterExpression(LogicalOperator.Or);
foreach (int value in values)
{
    filter.AddCondition(new ConditionExpression(fieldName, 
        ConditionOperator.ContainValues, value));
}
query.Criteria.AddFilter(filter);
```

Just wondering if there is a better solution than this one?

Comment: What's the exception you get when passing `values` as a third argument?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `In`.

[Query data from multi-select picklists](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/multi-select-picklist#query-data-from-multi-select-picklists)

> With the Web API there are the equivilent `ContainValues` and
>   `DoesNotContainValues` query functions.
>
> Other existing condition operators that can be used with this type of
>   attribute include: `Equal`, `NotEqual`, `NotNull`, `Null`, `In` and
>   `NotIn`.

Comment: In is not the correct way, and it doesn't solve the exception problem. You can even see in the documentation: int[] hikingValue = new int[] { 2 };
ConditionExpression condition = new ConditionExpression("sample_outdooractivities", ConditionOperator.ContainValues, hikingValue); the problem is that this part of code throw exception...

Answer (score 0):

The documentation obviously needs to be updated. The method definition takes an object array:

```
public void AddCondition(string attributeName, ConditionOperator conditionOperator, params object[] values)
```

so it should work if you change your values array to:

```
object[] values = GetValues();
```

This works in my code:

```
object[] roleValues = new object[] { (int)optionset_value };
```